# Constant velocity and linear acceleration

Tags: kinematics

Given an object moving in a straight line with velocity that can be modeled by a parabola, would the answer to the question "when is the velocity constant" be the vertex of the velocity graph (when the derivative of the graph/acceleration is 0)? It makes sense mathematically, but intuitively that point of 0 acceleration is not given any time to create "constant velocity".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Given an object moving in a straight line with velocity that can be modeled by a parabola, would the answer to the question "when is the velocity constant" be the vertex of the velocity graph

This question makes sense only in mathematical sense, because velocity is constant only in that infinitesimally small time instant $dt$ when the acceleration is zero.

> but intuitively that point of 0 acceleration is not given any time to create "constant velocity".

In the context of your question, it is said that the velocity is *"instantaneously constant"*. To the best of my knowledge this does not have any physical meaning. Even with the best equipment we have, I do not see how would we be able to capture exactly that moment when the object velocity is constant in the given context.